# Android Layout scrteching

Tags: android

I have following layout in my android application.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bbg">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0">
            <TableRow>
                <EditText 
                    android:id="@+id/TestEdit"
                    android:hint="Test"  
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/TestButtin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text = "Test"/>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/MapView" android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="KEY" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, that when I change text in EditText using setText() method, if text is too long EditText scratches and pushes Button out of screen. I don't want EditText to scrath, but I want it to be also I want it to be "fill_parent" by default/

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

```
<EditText 
      android:id="@+id/TestEdit"
      android:text="EditText01dsfasdfadsfsdafdsafdasfasdfsadfdsfdfadfasdfsd"
      android:hint="Test"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `android:maxLength`, `android:maxEms`,`android:maxLines` properties to restrict the width of your EditText

Comment: also I wat it to be "fill_parent" by default

Comment: you can look at the minWidth and minEms properties for this.